# Hot to calculate FWHM for a gaussian curve fitted over a histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I have a histogram with a fitted gaussian curve, and I'd like to find and calculate the full width at half maximum for this curve. The data used in this code is a single column from a dataframe. I've included a link to an image of my plot. I'm new to python and have no idea how to do this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gaussian(n, mean, amplitude, standard_deviation):
     return amplitude * np.exp( - (n - mean)**2 / (2*standard_deviation ** 2))

n = df_OI_CMC['Area_1_Micrometers']

#Plot Histogram 1
bin_heights, bin_borders, _ = plt.hist(n, bins = 
(0,1,5,10,25,50,75,100,125,150,200,250,500,750,1000,2500,5000,7500,10000), label='histogram', 
edgecolor ='white')
bin_widths = np.diff(bin_borders)
bin_centers = bin_borders[:-1] + np.diff(bin_borders) / 2

#Generate enough x values to make the curves look smooth
n_interval_for_fit = np.linspace(bin_borders[0], bin_borders[-1], 10000)
n_interval_for_fit_2 = np.linspace(bin_borders[0], bin_borders_2[-1], 10000)

#CurveFit to Histogram
popt, _ = curve_fit(gaussian, bin_centers, bin_heights, p0=[-44.0543433, 
1480.64682738,68.86641026])

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [12,12]
plt.plot(n_interval_for_fit, gaussian(n_interval_for_fit, *popt), label='fit')

plt.ylim([0, 1500])
plt.xlim([-10,1000])
```

[image]

Comment: `popt` has as its last item `standard_deviation`. For a Gaussian, FWHM is approximately 2.355 of standard deviation (wikipedia). You can use just that.

Comment: Ok, I've got this: popt [ -44.0446957  1480.54855421   68.86187251]. Is the 68.86187251 value the one I'm looking for? Then my FWHM will be (68.86187251 * 2.355) = 162.15?

Comment: Yep, and it looks roughly right considering the plot. You can add some horizontal and vertical lines to visually confirm if you want.